# Solspace Freeform File Upload links in CP

Tags: solspace-freeform

Looking at the File Field Uploads screen in Freeform, there are three links to the file, File Name (opens a modal), a Download button, and Front End Link.

Only the Front End Link works for me. If I click on File Name the modal says:

> The requested content cannot be loaded.
> Please try again later.

If I click on the Download button I get an EE error screen saying:

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> File filename.jpg does not exist.

My directory isn't above webroot or anything like that - any reason why these other links to the file aren't working?

It's Freeform 4.2.2 on EE 2.10.1

Comment: check your file upload prefs are configured correctly.
Did you check and see if the file in question made it to the folder?

Comment: Yes the file is there, the Front End Link works but not the other two kinds of links.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug with Freeform not using the full path to the file.

in the file:

```
system/expressionengine/third_party/freeform/default_fields/freeform_ft.file_upload.php
```

line 273, change this:

```
$mime = get_mime_by_extension($filename);
```

to this:

```
$mime = get_mime_by_extension($file_path);
```